# How to always intercept a Spring 4.x transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

We're using Spring 4.x, Hibernate 5.x, Spring-Data 1.11 and we currently have a SQL interceptor that extends `org.hiberate.EmptyInterceptor` and we basically manually hook that up at the start of the web request using `HibernateInterceptor.setInterceptor`. We also have jobs that run in the background via Spring task scheduler. These start their own transactions that obviously don't get the interceptor attached to them. What I'm trying to do at this point is to find a way to intercept Spring's @Transactional in all cases.

I've looked into `TransactionInterceptor`, and `@TransactionalEventListener` and so far haven't gotten any of them to work, and it's hard to figure out what is currently considered best practice with Spring.

So basically the problem we're trying to solve is that a the end of a transaction we need to know if it failed or succeeded.

So what is the current best practice with Spring to always get pre/post commit events so we can respond as needed?

**edit**

Realized that the `@TransactionalEventListener` wouldn't work as we're not using Spring events so it was just a misunderstanding on my part of what that really did.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#transaction-bound-events

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is to create a simple aspect, something like:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AfterTransactionalAspect {

    @After("@annotation(Transactional)")
    public void cleanupAfterTransaction(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {  
        // ... Do cleanup work here
    }
```

Another good way to go (if you're using Spring-destined events) would be to use the `@TransactionalEventListener`.

Are you sure you're using an `ApplicationEventPublisher` to publish the events? Do you for sure have `@EnableTransactionManagement` on your config, `@TransactionalEventListener` is on a public method, `TransactionTemplate` is set, using `@Transactional` on the method the publish event occurs?

Comment: I did some more reading on TransactionalEventListerner, and I guess I misunderstood it. In our case we're not publishing events through Spring ourselves, so it wouldn't really work for us. We need to do some cleanup stuff at the end of transactions though, so that's why we're interested when the end of any transaction happens.

Comment: Alright, you could create an aspect that does that for you (like the interceptor), but you could make it explicit. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it doesn't seem to be firing from our web services. In the end we have another work around that will work, but I'm surprised that Spring doesn't have a better way to do this. Seems like it would have be a common request, but guess not.

Comment: I think the reason for lack of a better way is that we typically don't handle "Transactions" so broadly. Remember that Transactions can range from JDBC transactions, to JMS, etc. In your example, cleanup for each one of those transaction types may be different.
When it's more localized, one can use a `TransactionSynchronizationManager` or for exceptions using specific-case exception handling (`@Transactional.rollbackFor` or bubbling exceptions up and using try-catch, etc.) which Spring provides ample support for.